# NullPointer Exception in Java tetris game

Tags: java, tetris

Hello I am relatively new to java and I am writing a tetris style program. I am currently getting a nullpointerException like this :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at tetris2.GameBoard.drawSquare(Tetris.java:359)
at tetris2.GameBoard.paint(Tetris.java:250)
```

I have marked out the lines where the exception is pointing to. I understand what a NulPointerException is but I cant work out what class that I have referenced without creating 
here is my code:

```
public class Tetris {

public static void createGUI()
{
    final JFrame frame = new JFrame("159.235 - A2");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    final JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    frame.setContentPane(contentPane);

    final GameBoard gameBoard = new GameBoard();
    contentPane.add(gameBoard, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
        {
            gameBoard.keyTyped(e);

        }

        @Override
        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
        {
            gameBoard.keyReleased(e);
        }

        @Override
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
        {
            switch (e.getKeyChar()) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE:
                gameBoard.pauseGame();
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            default:
                gameBoard.keyPressed(e);
            }
        }
    });

    frame.pack();
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    // Note: you might want to add a button to start, pause, or resume the
    // game instead of automatically starting it here
    gameBoard.startGame();
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            createGUI();
        }
    });
}
}


class GameBoard extends JPanel implements KeyListener {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

// the number of rows and columns on the game board
public static final int NUM_COLS = 10;
public static final int NUM_ROWS = 20;

// the size of each cell in pixels
public static final int CELL_SIZE = 20;

// the game board size in pixels
public  final int GAME_FIELD_WIDTH = NUM_COLS * CELL_SIZE;
public  final int GAME_FIELD_HEIGHT = NUM_ROWS * CELL_SIZE;

// the interval between game state updates
private int m_updateInterval = 500;







// the game timer initiates an update to the game state
private final Timer m_gameTimer = new Timer(m_updateInterval,
        new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                if(isFallingFinished) {
                    isFallingFinished = false;
                    newPiece();;
                } else {
                    oneLineDown();
                }
            }
        });

// the game board, with [0][0] being the bottom left cell
//private final Block[][] m_cells = new Block[NUM_ROWS][NUM_COLS];

// the currently active shape
private Shapes m_currentShape = new Shapes();



public int curX = 0;
public int curY = 0;
tetrisPieces[] board;
boolean isFallingFinished = false;
boolean isStarted = false;
boolean isPaused = false;   
int numLinesRemoved = 0;

// ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public GameBoard()
{
    setMinimumSize(new Dimension(GAME_FIELD_WIDTH + 1, GAME_FIELD_HEIGHT));
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(GAME_FIELD_WIDTH + 1, GAME_FIELD_HEIGHT));
    setOpaque(true);

    // set-up the timer for the render loop
    m_gameTimer.setInitialDelay(m_updateInterval);
    m_gameTimer.setRepeats(true);
    board = new tetrisPieces[GAME_FIELD_WIDTH * GAME_FIELD_HEIGHT];
    clearBoard();
    newPiece();



}



int squareWidth() { return (int) getSize().getWidth() / GAME_FIELD_WIDTH;}
int squareHeight() { return (int) getSize().getHeight() / GAME_FIELD_HEIGHT; }
tetrisPieces shapeAt(int x, int y) { return board[(y * GAME_FIELD_WIDTH) + x]; }

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
{
    switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
    case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
        m_currentShape.rotateShape();
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN: // move down
        oneLineDown();
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT: // move left
        tryMove(m_currentShape, curX - 1, curY);
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT: // move right
        tryMove(m_currentShape, curX + 1, curY);
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE: // toggle pause / resume
        if (m_gameTimer.isRunning()) pauseGame();
        else startGame();
        break;
    }
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
{
    switch (e.getKeyCode()) {
    case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN: // disable down key
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT: // disable left key
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT: // disable right key
        break;
    }
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
{}

public void startGame()
{
    if(isPaused)
        return;

    isStarted = true;
    isFallingFinished = false;
    numLinesRemoved = 0;
    clearBoard();

    board = new tetrisPieces[getWidth() * getHeight()];
    newPiece();
    m_gameTimer.start();
}

public void pauseGame()
{
    if (!isStarted)
            return;

        isPaused = !isPaused;
        if(isPaused) {
            m_gameTimer.stop();
            //statusbar.setText("paused");
        } else {
            m_gameTimer.start();
            //statusbar.setText(String.valueOf(numLinesRemoved));
            }
            repaint();
}


public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    super.paint(g);

    Dimension size = getSize();
    int boardTop = (int) size.getHeight() - GAME_FIELD_HEIGHT * squareHeight();

    for (int i = 0; i < GAME_FIELD_HEIGHT; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < GAME_FIELD_WIDTH; ++j) {
            tetrisPieces shapes = shapeAt(j, GAME_FIELD_HEIGHT - i -1);
            if (shapes != tetrisPieces.noPiece)
                drawSquare(g, 0 + j * squareWidth(),boardTop + i * squareHeight(), shapes); 
               //**This line above**
        }
    }

    if(m_currentShape.getShape() != tetrisPieces.noPiece) {
        for(int i = 0; i <4; ++i) {
            int x = curX + + m_currentShape.x(i);
            int y = curY - m_currentShape.y(i);
            drawSquare(g, 0 + x * squareWidth(), 
                          boardTop + (GAME_FIELD_HEIGHT - y - 1) * squareHeight(),
                          m_currentShape.getShape());
        }
    }
}




private void oneLineDown()
{
    if(!tryMove(m_currentShape, curX, curY - 1))
        pieceDropped();
}

private void clearBoard() {
    for (int i = 0; i <GAME_FIELD_HEIGHT * GAME_FIELD_WIDTH; ++i)
        board[i] = tetrisPieces.noPiece;
}


private boolean tryMove(Shapes newPiece, int newX, int newY) {
    for(int i = 0; i< 4; ++i) {
        int x = newX + newPiece.x(i);
        int y = newY - newPiece.y(i);
        if( x < 0 || x >= GAME_FIELD_WIDTH || y < 0 || y >= GAME_FIELD_HEIGHT)
            return false;
        if(shapeAt(x, y) != tetrisPieces.noPiece)
            return false;
    }

    m_currentShape = newPiece;
    curX = newX;
    curY = newY;
    repaint();
    return true;
}

private void pieceDropped() {
    for (int i =0; i < 4; ++i) {
        int x = curX + m_currentShape.x(i);
        int y = curY - m_currentShape.y(i);
        board[(y * GAME_FIELD_WIDTH) + x] = m_currentShape.getShape();
    }

    removeFullLines();

    if(!isFallingFinished)
        newPiece();
}

private void removeFullLines() {

    int numFullLines = 0;

    for(int i = GAME_FIELD_HEIGHT -1; i >= 0; --i) {
        boolean lineIsFull = true;

        for(int j = 0; j < GAME_FIELD_WIDTH; ++j) {
            if(shapeAt(j, i) == tetrisPieces.noPiece) {
                lineIsFull = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(lineIsFull) {
            ++numFullLines;
            for(int k = i; k < GAME_FIELD_HEIGHT - 1; ++k) {
                for(int j = 0; j < GAME_FIELD_WIDTH; ++j)
                    board[(k* GAME_FIELD_WIDTH) + j] = shapeAt(j, k + 1);
            }
         }
    }
}

private void newPiece() {
     m_currentShape.setRandomShape();
    curX = GAME_FIELD_WIDTH / 2 + 1;
    curY = GAME_FIELD_HEIGHT - 1 + m_currentShape.minY();

    if(!tryMove(m_currentShape, curX, curY)) {
        m_currentShape.setShape(tetrisPieces.noPiece);
        m_gameTimer.stop();
        isStarted = false;

    }
}



private void drawSquare(Graphics g, int x, int y, tetrisPieces shape)
{
    Color colors[] = { new Color(0, 0, 0), new Color(204, 102, 102),
                          new Color(102, 204, 102), new Color(102, 102, 204), 
                          new Color(204, 204, 102), new Color(204, 102, 204), 
                          new Color(102, 204, 204), new Color(218, 170, 0)
        };

Color color = colors[shape.ordinal()]; //**This line here**

g.setColor(color);
g.fillRect(x + 1, y + 1, squareWidth() - 2, squareHeight() - 2);

g.setColor(color.brighter());
g.drawLine(x, y + squareHeight() - 1, x, y);
g.drawLine(x, y, x + squareWidth() - 1, y);

g.setColor(color.darker());
        g.drawLine(x + 1, y + squareHeight() - 1,
                    x + squareWidth() - 1, y + squareHeight() - 1);
        g.drawLine(x + squareWidth() - 1, y + squareHeight() - 1,
                        x + squareWidth() - 1, y + 1);
}
}
```

The Shapes class:

```
public class Shapes {

enum tetrisPieces { noPiece, ZShape, SSHape, TShape, LShape, SquareShape,
                    ReverseLShape}

private tetrisPieces pieceShape;
private int coords[][];
private int coordsTable[][][];


public Shapes() {

    coords = new int[4][2];
    setShape(tetrisPieces.noPiece);

}

public void setShape(tetrisPieces shape) {

    coordsTable = new int[][][] {
        { { 0, 0 },   { 0, 0 },   { 0, 0 },   { 0, 0 } },
        { { 0, -1 },  { 0, 0 },   { -1, 0 },  { -1, 1 } },
        { { 0, -1 },  { 0, 0 },   { 1, 0 },   { 1, 1 } },
        { { 0, -1 },  { 0, 0 },   { 0, 1 },   { 0, 2 } },
        { { -1, 0 },  { 0, 0 },   { 1, 0 },   { 0, 1 } },
        { { 0, 0 },   { 1, 0 },   { 0, 1 },   { 1, 1 } },
        { { -1, -1 }, { 0, -1 },  { 0, 0 },   { 0, 1 } },
        { { 1, -1 },  { 0, -1 },  { 0, 0 },   { 0, 1 } }
    };

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j<2; ++j) {
            coords[i][j] = coordsTable[shape.ordinal()][i][j];
        }
    }
    pieceShape = shape;

}

private void setX(int index, int x) { coords[index][0] = x; }
private void setY(int index, int y) { coords[index][1] = y; }
public int x(int index) { return coords[index][0]; }
public int y(int index) { return coords[index][1]; }
public tetrisPieces getShape() { return pieceShape; }

public void setRandomShape()
{
    Random r = new Random();
    int x = Math.abs(r.nextInt()) % 6 + 1;
    tetrisPieces[] values = tetrisPieces.values();
    setShape(values[x]);
}

public int minX() {
    int m =coords[0][0];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        m = Math.min(m, coords[i][0]);
    }
    return m;
}

public int minY() {
    int m = coords[0][1];
    for (int i =0; i <4; i++) {
        m = Math.min(m, coords[i][1]);
    }
    return m;
}



public Shapes rotateShape() {
    if(pieceShape == tetrisPieces.SquareShape)
        return this;

    Shapes result = new Shapes();
    result.pieceShape = pieceShape;

    for(int i = 0; i <4; ++i) {
        result.setX(i, -y(i));
        result.setY(i, x(i));
    }
    return result;
   }
}
```

Comment: And which line is 359?  Put a break point in your code before this line, start the debugger and inspect the state of your variables...

Comment: So where's `Shapes` and `tetrisPieces`? Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This will result in less confusion and better responses. You might like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others

Comment: @MadProgrammer Okay sorry i forgot to put in my shapes class. I will read through the conventions thanks,althogh this is all based on skeleton code that the lecturer has given us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Color color = colors[shape.ordinal()];
```

The only thing that can be null at this line is `shape`, since colors is iniyialized the line before.

Where does shape come from? From the line

```
tetrisPieces shapes = shapeAt(j, GAME_FIELD_HEIGHT - i -1);
```

What does shapeAt() return?

```
tetrisPieces shapeAt(int x, int y) { return board[(y * GAME_FIELD_WIDTH) + x]; }
```

Have you initialized the elements of the `board` array before this line is executed? Probably not. The debugger will confirm that. What is probably buggy is these lines:

```
clearBoard();
board = new tetrisPieces[getWidth() * getHeight()];
```

The first one initializes every element of the board array, but the second throws away the initialized board array and replaces it by a new, empty one.

Comment: Okay thank you removing that line has removed that problem, once again thanks so much!